# linking a boolean from a service to multiple components

Tags: angular, angular6

To facilitate communication between two child components I've made a service layer. To check if I'm actually modifying an item or if I used the add button I'm using a boolean in my service layer. I'm doing this because the add button is in a different component than the modify button.

In the service layer I first import

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

And in the Service itself I've got

```
modifyToggle: boolean = false;

getModifyToggle(): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(this.modifyToggle);
} //returns error: "Illegal return statement"
```

Things are going wrong on this function, which I found strange because I've got similar code to return a report and that works fine.

In the child components I've got

```
modifyLine: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
     this.reportLinkService.getModifyToggle().subscribe(
        toggle => this.modifyLine = toggle
     );
}
```

When I change the modifyLine in my child component, I want it to change in my service layer aswell, making the change to all my components which use this 'modifyToggle'.

---

the full service code is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { Report } from '../../classes/report';
import { LineItem } from '../../classes/lineItem';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReportLinkService {

  modifyToggle: boolean = false;
  report: Report;

  constructor() {}

  addLine(lineItem: LineItem): void {
    this.report.lineItems.push(lineItem);
  }

  getReport(): Observable<Report> {
    return of(this.report);
  }

  getDate(): Date {
    return this.report.date;
  }

  deleteLine (lineItem: LineItem ): void {
    this.report.lineItems = this.report.lineItems.filter( line => line !== lineItem);
  }

  reportLine(): void{
    // temp. using this as a checker, will be modified to something useable
    console.log(this.modifyToggle); 
  }

  getModifyToggle():Observable<boolean> {
    return of(this.modifyToggle);
  }

  getReportLine(id: number): Observable<LineItem> {
    return of(this.report.lineItems.find(item => item.id === id));
  }
}
```

---

No real error is thrown, but when i debug and I pass over the subscribe function in the component, when I check the value of modifyLine, i get:

```
message: "Illegal return statement"
stack: "SyntaxError: Illegal return statement   at LineItemComponent.push../src/app/report/line-item/line-item.component.ts.LineItemComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1010:27)↵    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63659:19)↵    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:64923:20)↵    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:64885:16)↵    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65518:38)↵    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65478:13)↵    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///ReportModule/ReportComponent.ngfactory.js:63:5)↵    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65470:21)↵    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:64867:14)↵    at callViewAction (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65108:21)"
__proto__: Error
constructor: ƒ SyntaxError()
message: ""
name: "SyntaxError"
toString: ƒ toString()
__proto__: Object
```

---

As a demo I made this stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdpuvc

Comment: "Things are going wrong" Maybe follow up on this.

Comment: 1. Can you post the full code of the service file?

2. Using `of` will return an observable with only 1 value and will complete itself instantly. So, consider using a `Subject` to track `modifyToggle` change, or better, use a state management system, if your app is complex enough to need it.

Comment: @Tr1et added the full service like you asked

Comment: The service looks legit to me. How about the full error? Is `Illegal return statement` an IDE error?

Comment: I added respons to the question

Comment: Not a direct answer to your problem, but you may want to use NGRX (cf. for instance https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-ngrx-a-clean-and-clear-introduction-4ed61c89c1fc). Probably overkill for small applications though.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use BehaviorSubject or Subject to achieve the same thing. Your code should be like  -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { Report } from '../../classes/report';
import { LineItem } from '../../classes/lineItem';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReportLinkService {

  modifyToggle: boolean = false; //<-- you can remove this.
  report: Report;
    public toggle: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = 
new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor() {}

  addLine(lineItem: LineItem): void {
    this.report.lineItems.push(lineItem);
  }

  getReport(): Observable<Report> {
    return of(this.report);
  }

  getDate(): Date {
    return this.report.date;
  }

  deleteLine (lineItem: LineItem ): void {
    this.report.lineItems = this.report.lineItems.filter( line => line !== lineItem);
  }

  reportLine(): void{
    this.toggle.next(true); //<--- you can change the value here.
    // temp. using this as a checker, will be modified to something useable
    console.log(this.modifyToggle); 
  }

  getModifyToggle():Observable<boolean> {
    return this.toggle.asObservable();     //<--- change here
  }

  getReportLine(id: number): Observable<LineItem> {
    return of(this.report.lineItems.find(item => item.id === id));
  }
}
```

### Usages

You can use following syntax in the `constructor` of your component like `LineItemComponent`

```
this.reportLinkService.getModifyToggle().subscribe(value=>console.log("toggle value ", value));
```

Here is the sample demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ru5jmk

Comment: Changed my service to your code, then called in my component following code:(but still getting the same error)                            
modifyLine: boolean;

  constructor( private reportLinkService: ReportLinkService ) { 
    this.reportLinkService.getModifyToggle().subscribe(toggle => this.modifyLine = toggle);
  }

Comment: Updated the answer with `this.reportLinkService.getModifyToggle().subscribe(value=>console.log("toggle value ", value));`

Comment: So i don't see what's wrong with linking the variable in the child in this function call? `this.reportLinkService.getModifyToggle().subscribe(toggle => this.modifyLine = toggle);` should be correct then? (It's still saying `"Illegal return statement"`)

Comment: Then there is issue with some other line. You can refer the demo link , its working fine. If issue still persist, please create stackblitz demo.

Comment: So how does my second child component see when the toggle has changed if I can't link it directly to a variable with the code you supplied? You're right that this code works, and if I click a button in a component that it'll change in the service, but both components are active at the same time on my page, so when component A changes the toggle, Component B should take action. How can I get that working?

Comment: I've made a stackblitz demo as requested: Link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdpuvc

Comment: Multiple problems in your in the demo:
- `modifyToggle` is never changed in the service.
- reportLinkService.getModifyToggle() will only be triggered once when you start the app

This answer sets you on the right path. Create a behaviour subject and call `next` when you press the button

Comment: You need to toggle value into the services which will notify all other `subscriber`. Here is your modified demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ru5jmk

Comment: I see, I assumed (incorrectly) that subscribing meant a two way binding. I'll try it out on my solution.